# Need a quick translation

Tags: american-english, translation

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> What is the Need you are going after?
>
> ```
> **Edit** here is the context
> ```
>
> 1) PowerPoint presentation
>
> Intro (4 – 5 slides)
>
> a)      What is the Need you are going after?
>
> b)      What is the problem we are trying to solve?
>
> c)      Your Solution to problem

Comment: Without context, I think the main "meaning" we can infer from this is that the writer isn't a native speaker of English. I'd guess he's simply trying to find a different way of saying *"What exactly do you want?"*, but unfortunately what he's come up with just sounds clumsy.

Comment: The context came like my edit

Comment: Fumble is correct, but I guess '"What exactly do you *still* want?" fits  better what that phrase means.

Comment: @Mutawe: That edit is certainly useful, thank you. Personally I've still got no idea what difference there might be between sections (a) and (b)  of the presentation. But I'd hazard a guess those section names came from an "Indian English" speaker. If so, and if "need" has some special connotations in the context of Indian English and marketing strategy, perhaps someone else here will know it. But there's not meaningfully a difference here between a ***need*** and a ***problem one is trying to solve*** in standard English.

Comment: I may well be wrong but I think this might be business/management speak rather than an accident/fumble (the capital letter supports this). I think it's to distinguish between a tangible thing you want ('My Need is a new computer') and the steps to getting that ('My Want is for you to go a buy me a computer').

I don't exactly exist in the business world, but that's my interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that this is ordinary PowerPoint English, probably from a presentation on starting a business.

Comment: @StoneyB: Not sure what you mean by "ordinary" in this context. My comment was motivated by the fact that "need" (and esp. "needful") are often used rather oddly in "Indian English", ***and*** it's (again, rather "oddly") capitalised in OP's citation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This use of *need* is ordinary in US BizSpeak; and, alas, random capitalization and syntax isn't unusual either. That's what happens when you put a tool like PowerPoint in the hands of amateurs. (If that sounds personally bitter, it's because it is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very ordinary BizSpeak. The speaker may be talking about *How to sell something-or-other*, or *How to start a business*, or *How to chair a task force*, but the basic principle is the same for all these. You have to start by asking what **need** is being met by your activity, because unless your activity meets some defined **need** nobody will pay you to do it. Defining that **need** provides a focus for your subsequent activity (How to meet the **need**) and a metric for evaluating your activity (How well you have met the **need**).

But if there is a need, there must be people who need it, and those needy people are your possible customers or clients. These are the people who will pay you for your activity, because your activity satisfies their **need**. **Need** therefore implies a *market* for your activity, a market you are presumably **going after** in the sense of “pursuing”, trying to “capture”, trying to sell something to.

So “What is the Need you are going after?” may be paraphrased

> What need are you trying to meet, and who will pay you to meet it?